# Is response_type=token supported by Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring-authorization-server

Does anybody know if Spring Authorization Server supports response_type=token. I have used response_type as code and it works fine. Was confused about response_type = token, if supported or not as other IDAMs like WSO2 IS supports.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 (RFC 6749), [Section 3.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.1) states:

```
 response_type
         REQUIRED.  The value MUST be one of "code" for requesting an
         authorization code as described by Section 4.1.1, "token" for
         requesting an access token (implicit grant) as described by
         Section 4.2.1, or a registered extension value as described by
         Section 8.4.
```

while OAuth 2.1 (draft), [Section 10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-05#section-10) omits the implicit grant:

> The Implicit grant (response_type=token) is omitted from this specification as per Section 2.1.2 of [I-D.ietf-oauth-security-topics]

Since Spring Authorization Server seeks to [support OAuth 2.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/overview.html#introducing-spring-authorization-server), it does not support the implicit grant, and therefore does not support `response_type=token`. Currently, only `response_type=code` is supported. See [#205](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/205) for pending support of `response_type` with OIDC-related specifications.